# Returning values from MyBatis <insert> mapped methods

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

I have a Java project that uses MyBatis to access a PostgreSQL database. PostgreSQL allows to return fields of a newly created row after an `INSERT` statement, and I want to use it to return the auto-generated `BIGSERIAL` `id` of newly created records. So, I change the `insert` command in the XML to use feature of PostgreSQL, add an `resultType="long"` attribute to the `<insert>` tag, and in the Java interface of the mapper I set the insertion method to return `long` instead of `void`.

When I try to run this, I get an `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` saying that `Attribute "resultType" must be declared for element type "insert"`.

Now, when I change the `<insert>` tag to `<select>` everything works fine, but it bothers me that I use `<select>` tag to perform an `INSERT` statement.

Is there a way to make methods mapped to `<insert>` tags return results, or is MyBatis not designed for that, and I should just keep them as `<select>` tags?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The return type of mapped insert method can be `void` or `int` (in which case it will return the number of the inserted row). You can do the following mechanism to return the generated id:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterClass="MyParameter">
  <selectKey order="AFTER" keyProperty="id" resultType="long">
    SELECT currval('my_seq')
  </selectKey>
  INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2) VALUES (#{val1}, #{val2})
</insert>
```

This will set generated `id` column to `id` property of your parameter class. After that, object you passed as parameter will have generated `id` set in its property.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to use this with PostgreSQL's `RETURNING` syntax?

Comment: You can try add `useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id"`. I never used this but it should work. No need to use `returning` in query, let this job do JDBC driver and MyBatis. See [this link](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2010/12/beginning-mybatis-3-part-3-how-to-get-tables-generated-ids/) for additional help.

Comment: OK, I looked at [these docs](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/configreference/generatedKey.html) and it looks like it does essentially the same thing - runs a second query to retrieve the key. Also, it is not defined for PostgreSQL, which makes sense - since in PostgreSQL you can get the key from the same query that inserted the row.

Comment: Basically when you want to execute query with `returning` only way to get that value is from `ResultSet` which means you can't use `executeUpdate` which is used in MyBatis `<update>`. So it can't be executed with `<insert>`.

Comment: @partlov Regarding `RETURNING` and `ResultSet`, is there a downside for using `INSERT... RETURNING` within a `<select>`? (Would the MyBatis cache need to be cleared, for example, or is there even more to it?)

Comment: Well, probably not, bu I can't be completely sure. Besides it is not natural, there is possibility to optimize transaction if there are just reading queries in it, and inside `<select>` it should be just reading query. I'm not sure but possible this can have influence if this is part of some bigger transaction and because of some "optimizations" this can end up in separate transaction. These are just guesses, probably nothing of this is not big problem at all :)

Comment: Is this "returning number of inserted rows" feature documented somewhere in mybatis's official doc?

Comment: What is `currval('my_seq')`?

Comment: @SeakyLone That return current value of sequence with provided name (my_seq). That should be sequence used to populate primary key of table you are inserting value into.

Comment: When you have multiple statements inside `<insert>`, for example
<`insert id="save">
    select ... for update;
    insert....
  </insert>`
Int method will always return -1

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways (at least that I know) to get the ID of the one inserted record:

For example, we have a class `EntityDao`:

```
public class EntityDao {
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     // other fields, getters and setters
}
```

---

### 1. Using the `insert` tag and returning an instance of object

MyBatis interface

```
public interface EntityDaoMapper {
    EntityDao insert(EntityDao entity);
}
```

MyBatis XML mapper:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.package.EntityDao" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="entity_id" keyProperty="id">
    INSERT INTO some_table (name, type, other_fields, etc)
    VALUES (#{name}, #{type}, #{other_fields}, #{etc}) 
</insert>
```

Sample code:

```
    EntityDao saved = entityDaoMapper.insert(entityToSave);
    System.out.println(saved.getId());
```

### 2. Using `select` and `resultType` tags to return the ID of the record only

MyBatis interface

```
public interface EntityDaoMapper {
    Long insert(EntityDao entity);
}
```

MyBatis XML mapper:

```
<select id="insert" parameterType="com.package.EntityDao" resultType="long">
    INSERT INTO some_table (name, type, other_fields, etc)
    VALUES (#{name}, #{type}, #{other_fields}, #{etc}) 
    RETURNING entity_id       <-- id only or many fields
</select>
```

Sample code:

```
Long id = entityDaoMapper.insert(entityToSave);
System.out.println(id);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use as follows. In xml

```
 <insert id="insertNewUser" parameterType="User">
            <selectKey keyProperty="userId" resultType="Integer" order="BEFORE">
                select NEXTVAL('base.user_id_seq')
            </selectKey>
            INSERT INTO base.user(
                user_id, user_name)
            VALUES (#{userId}, #{userName});
    </insert>
```

In Java class from where you have called the method to insert, you can get the value by calling `user.getUserId()`.

Basically the next val is stored inside the variable of the object. `Here userId inside User.`

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done with Java `Records` and mybatis annotations

Entity:

```java
record UserEntity (
    int id,
    String name,
){}
```

Mapper:

```java
@Select("INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (#{name}) returning id")
int create(UserEntity entity);
```

The key here is to use `@Select` instead of `@Insert` and having `returning id` at the end of sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use generated keys:

```
  <insert id="create" parameterType="Skupina" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id">
        INSERT INTO ODBOR 
            (NAZEV, POPIS, ZKRATKA, WEBROLE, JEODBOR, AKTIVNI)
        VALUES 
            (#{nazev}, #{popis}, #{webrole}, #{webrole}, false, #{aktivni})
  </insert>
```

After insert, parameter has property **id** set to value from column **id**.

Answer (score 1):

In this example using options

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Options;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

@Mapper
public interface POJOCustomMapper {
    @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "ID", keyColumn = "ID") 
    @Insert({
        "insert into TABLE_A ( NAME "
        "values (#{NAME,jdbcType=VARCHAR})"
    })
    long insert(POJO record);
```

Comment: Not work for me. I have to add `returning id` and use `@Select` without `@Options`.

Comment: If you use \@Select instead of \@Insert it will start working ;) Do not forget to add "returning ID" at the end of the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'returning' to return an instance of object

```
<select id="insertOrderHeader" resultType="com.***.entity.OrderHeader">
    insert into order_header_t (order_id, delete_flag, organization_code)
    values (#{query.orderId}, #{query.deleteFlag}, #{query.organizationCode})
        returning order_id as orderId, delete_flag as deleteFlag, organization_code as organizationCode
</select>
```