# Return ID in MyBatis and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

My table plugins has just two columns: ID and DTYPE. I would like to store a String in DTYPE column. ID should increment automatically and be returned by insert method. For that purpose I created manually "id_sequence" like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_sequence
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
START 1
CACHE 1;
OWNED BY plugin.id;
```

This is my mapper.xml file:

```
<insert id="insert"  useGeneratedKeys="true" parameterType="String">
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
        SELECT CAST(nextval('id_sequence') as INTEGER) 
    </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO plugins (ID, DTYPE) 
    VALUES ( #{id}, #{plugin}) 
            RETURNING ID;  

</insert>
```

and corresponding mapper.java:

```
int insert(String plugin);
```

Problem statement: 1) I cannot get a proper value of ID (it is null), 2) I get an error

```
 SQL: INSERT INTO public.ucpoplugin (ID, DTYPE)    VALUES ( ?, CORRECT_STRING)
 Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Column »id« is of type bigint, but the sentence is has Type character varying.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend to use auto increment on that id column and then do not pass just string as parameter, but pass whole object. After insert that property will be filled.

See: http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2010/12/beginning-mybatis-3-part-3-how-to-get-tables-generated-ids/

Or: [Returning values from MyBatis <insert> mapped methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456033/returning-values-from-mybatis-insert-mapped-methods)